# FIFO content is not printed

Tags: bash

I have (binary) data coming from the named fifo `outfile`, and I want to replace null bytes by the string `NULL`. I want to redirect the result to another FIFO. But calling `cat` would not output anything:

```
...
mkfifo outfile2
LC_ALL=C sed 's/\x0/NULL/g' < outfile > outfile2
cat < outfile2
```

... while the following will output everything as expected – but I cannot further use the result as input:

```
mkfifo outfile2
LC_ALL=C sed 's/\x0/NULL/g' < outfile
```

Of course the input fifo is filled as

```
cat < outfile
```

shows.

How can I make this work as expected?

Comment: Works fine for me. I have to toss an `&` after the `sed` command to be able to continue using the console, but once I run the `cat` it spits out the expected answer

Comment: @JNevill Thank you, that's correct, and it's of course necessary!